# MySQL Query: display the number of posts for each unique city

Tags: mysql

I'm not very good at database queries. Need help with what is probably a simple query.

***Database: MYSQL***

### zipcodes [table]

```
zip | city | state
```

### post [table]

```
post_id | title | post | zip
```

I need to display the number of posts for each unique city.

Comment: Are these tables that you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM post LEFT JOIN zipcodes ON post.zip = zipcodes.zip GROUP BY city;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. This would display the city name in the output and also show teh cities for which there are no posts exist.

```
SELECT city,count(*) as "num_posts" FROM zipcodes LEFT JOIN post ON post.zip = zipcodes.zip GROUP BY city;
```